# How to make an element overflow outside of containing element?

Tags: css, menu

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            *{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .squares {
                color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
                background-color: #2e2e2e;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
            }

            .dropdown-content {
                width: 100px;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: #7e7e7e;
            }
            #sidebar{
                overflow: visible;
                width: 40px;
                height: 100px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="squares"></div>
            <div class="dropdown-content"></div>
            <div class="squares"></div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make .dropdown-content overflow to the right side of #sidebar without changing size of sidebar? I've tried using floats but that did not work. I've also tried containing the first .squares and .dropdown-content together but that causes the second .squares to be positioned away  from the bottom of the first .squares.

Comment: `overflow: visible` on `#sidebar` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that but how do I get it to overflow to the right in the first place?

Comment: It overflows to the right by default.

Comment: It doesn't because #sidebar's width is set to 40px which is smaller than .dropdown-content.

Comment: A snippet could be useful.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Added.

Comment: Did you try to use absolute positioning?

Comment: I did not but I think that wouldn't be elegant since I want to use multiple of these.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add relative positioning to your `.dropdown-content` and absolute positioning to the inner sub menu wrapper. And then add `top: 0` and `left: 100%`

Here's the working example for you:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.menu {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #212121;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible;
}

.menu-item {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.expandable {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.expandable:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-menu-item {
    padding: 10px;
}

.sub-menu-item:not(:last-child) {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">Simple Menu</div>
    <div class="menu-item expandable">
        Hover to Expand >
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <div class="sub-menu-item">Sub Menu 1</div>
            <div class="sub-menu-item">Sub Menu 2</div>
            <div class="sub-menu-item">Sub Menu 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">Simple Menu</div>
</div>
```

In my code `.expandable` is the one that have sub menus in it, on hovering over the element submenus will be opened on the right side of that menu-item.
The position will be depend upon the hovered element.

Also, here's the code pen link if you wish to tinker it:
https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/zYBeWEz?editors=0110

In this one I have used multiple of this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Works perfectly. Did not know that "position: absolute" was "relative to its closest positioned ancestor". I have one question though what does left 100% mean? What is it 100% of?

Comment: When you make an element's position absolute/fixed/relative/sticky, you can adjust the position as per the requirement. There are 4 properties for that, top, bottom, left and right. So when I mentioned that left should be 100%, that means I want that element should have 100% space on left side (width of that element) that means 200px space on the left side relative to its parent container. Because of this it won't get overlapped on the main menu items and causing it to render on the right side of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
        .dropdown-content {
            position: relative;
            right: -20px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: #7e7e7e;
        }
```

simple version I do not change the container, and I shift it to the right.
If I understood correctly....

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100px;
}

.squares {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #fff;

    color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 1);
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}


.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #7e7e7e;
    display: none; /* sub menus will not be visible as a result */
   
}

.squares:hover > .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="squares">1</div>
        <div class="squares">
            2
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <!-- create another container to house the .dropdown-content --> 
        <div class="squares">3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

insert the .dropdown-content into a .square then add display:none to the styling of .dropdown-content and finally on hover change display: none to block